# Configure Spring Boot + tomcat 8 to run on a non priviledged port

Tags: port, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I am have a working spring boot + tomcat8 embedded application that bind to ports 8080 (http) and 8888 (https). Now I am looking for a way to configure the application to run

a) on a privileged port i.e. port that is lower then 1024 i.e. port 80 and 443

b) the application should run under a non root user account.

c) the OS environment could be any Linux distro for example: debian/ubuntu or OpenBSD distro.

d) it is preferable for the solution to be configurable later on over the web interface i.e. some script.

All I found so far on the INTERNET was a manual to configure non embedded tomcat instance together with “authbind”. However I have an embedded tomcat.  The man page of “authbind” says:

> “  You  must invoke the program using authbind.  authbind will set up
>   some environment variables, including an LD_PRELOAD, which will allow
>   the program (including any subprocesses it may run) to bind to
>   low-numbered (<512) ports if the system is configured to allow this. “

I issued “ps – aux” and I got the user name under which the application is running. 
I have configured the embedded tomcat to run on ports 80 and 443 the ports i.e. and issued the commands in the cli:

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
chown tito /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/443
chown tito /etc/authbind/byport/443
```

Now how do I invoke the embedded tomcat under the “authbind”. If “authbind” is not the right solution for this problem then how to solve this problem with spring boot.

The error message I am getting is:

```
2014-05-09 09:46:48.403  INFO 7880 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 80
2014-05-09 09:46:48.604 ERROR 7880 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:351)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:683)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:826)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.syncServer.core.Application.main(Application.java:123)

2014-05-09 09:46:48.606 ERROR 7880 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:826)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.syncServer.core.Application.main(Application.java:123)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:351)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:683)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2014-05-09 09:46:48.840  INFO 7880 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-05-09 09:46:48.841  INFO 7880 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
2014-05-09 09:46:48.913  INFO 7880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-05-09 09:46:48.913  INFO 7880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1898 ms
SERVLET REGISTRATION
DISPATCHER INIT
```

ADDTION 1
i found a way how to do it from the command line i.e. from spring i do maven build with the goal set to  "package" then i go to the target folder where my jar/war file is and then i do

```
exec authbind --deep java -jar application.jar
```

The application is bound to the ports 80 and 443 but somehow my mvc thymeleaf templates got messed up. I need to automate this process trough spring sts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading between the lines you are trying to expose your Spring Boot application on port 80/443, but you don't really need to have it listening on one of those ports itself. Instead, you should use a reverse proxy such as [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), which will start up as root, but then jails itself in a chroot so that it has no root privileges.

You then configure the proxy to forward requests to whatever port your application is listening on.

Beyond security, this has additional advantages such as being able to forward based on the URL being used to multiple services. This is fantastic for Spring Boot micro-services, as it lets you expose multiple services at ports 80/443 on the same server, without giving any of those applications root privileges. It can also be used to provide hot-switching between application instances, which can help you achieve zero-downtime deployments.

Popular alternatives to [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) are [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/).

Comment: hello Steve, thank you for the reply. this idea is interesting and i will definetelly consider HAProxy for future projects, however on this project i do have a root account and i would install a proxy, but i do not what to use any additional layer i.e. haProxy etc. So is there any other way to bind spring boot app with embedded tomcat directly on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Not without running it as root - at least as far as I am aware

Comment: ok i found a way how to do it from the command line i.e. from spring i do maven build with the goal package then i go to the target folder where my jar/war file is and then i do ""exec authbind --deep java -jar application.jar" The application is bound to the ports 80 and 443 but somehow my mvc templates does not work. I need to automate this process trough spring sts

Comment: You can just use iptables to forward 80 and 443 to the ports tomcat is listening on. I do the equivolent on my mac for development.

Comment: this is not really what i was looking for i.e. to do port forwarding

Answer (score 0):

All staff you want is implemented in [Apache Daemon Tools](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/).

It provides chroot for java applications. So you can start it as root and bind to privileged port, then downgrade it to unprivileged user.